# Angular 7: How to properly parse backend responses to extract Date from string?

Tags: angular, typescript, deserialization, json-deserialization

I have function returning movie in service (but also another method returning collection of movies):

```
postNewMovie(movie: Movie): Observable<Movie> {
    const requestUrl = `${apiUrl}/create`;
    const movieJSON = JSON.stringify(movie);
    return this.http.post(requestUrl, movieJSON, httpOptions).pipe(
        tap((result: Movie) => console.log(`Posted movie with id = ${result.id} and title = ${result.title}!`))
    );
```

Model looks like this:

```
export class Movie {
    (...)
    releaseDate?: Date;

    constructor(obj: any) {
      (...)
      this.releaseDate = obj.releaseDate;
    }
}
```

Now, how to properly convert string release date from backend api call (it's in **ISO8601** format) and where should I do it? I saw similar answers advising to use some custom reviver function in JSON parser, but I could also do it in constructor of model, so what is the best approach?

Do you think I could use **moment.js** library for these kind of conversions or it's "overkill"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try it on your constructor in the model it should work

```
 this.releaseDate = (obj.releaseDate ) ? new Date(obj.releaseDate ) : new Date();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but unfortunately it seems not to work. The constructor does not get called at all for server response. When substitute above tap with below:
   
"tap((res: Movie) => console.log(res.releaseDate.constructor.name))"
                         
I get "String" type in console.

Comment: I think you need to call the constructor. So you can try like -> result: Movie = new Movie(result); I am not sure whether it will work or not. you may try

Comment: I think if your application small then it is not a problem. If you deal with the big application then you can create a model service from there you can call the constructor

Comment: I moved it to service, it seems to be better to do it there.